# Lua and complex numbers

Tags: lua, lua-table

I try to use complex numbers in a lua program.

I need to parse a table of complex numbers printing side by side the name of the complex number and its value. Can't get through it :

I don't ask how the library works.

```
require "complex"

a = complex.new (0,1)
b = complex.new (7,1) 
c = complex.new (1,6.4) 

t = {a="a",
    b="b",
    c="c"}

print (t["a"])
```

and here is `complex.lua`

```
--[[
--
--    ***   Complex   numbers   for   Lua   ***
--
--]]

-- Module "cmath" ... mathematic functions for complex numbers

module("cmath", package.seeall)

-- Logarithm

function log (x)
    local xx = complex.tocomplex(x)
    if ((xx.re <= 0) and (xx.im == 0)) then
        if (xx.re == 0) then
            return complex.new(-math.huge, 0)
        else
            return nil
        end
    else
        return complex.new(math.log(xx:abs()), xx:arg())
    end
end

function log10 (x)
    local xx = complex.tocomplex(x)
    return (log(xx) / log(10))
end

-- Exponent

function exp (x)
    local xx = complex.tocomplex(x)
    if (xx.im == 0) then
        return complex.new(math.exp(xx.re), 0)
    else
        return complex.new(
            math.exp(xx.re) * math.cos(xx.im),
            math.exp(xx.re) * math.sin(xx.im)
        )
    end
end

function pow (x, y)
    local base = complex.tocomplex(x)
    local exponent = complex.tocomplex(y)
    if (exponent.im ~= 0) then
        return exp(exponent * log(base))
    elseif ((base.re < 0) and (base.im == 0) and
        (exponent.re * 2 == math.floor(exponent.re * 2))) then
        if (math.floor(exponent.re * 2) % 4 == 0) then
            return complex.new((-base.re) ^ exponent.re, 0)
        elseif (math.floor(exponent.re * 2) % 4 == 1) then
            return complex.new(0, (-base.re) ^ exponent.re)
        elseif (math.floor(exponent.re * 2) % 4 == 2) then
            return complex.new(-((-base.re) ^ exponent.re), 0)
        elseif (math.floor(exponent.re * 2) % 4 == 3) then
            return complex.new(0, -((-base.re) ^ exponent.re))
        end
    elseif ((base.re == 0) and (base.im ~= 0) and
        (exponent.re == math.floor(exponent.re))) then
        if (math.floor(exponent.re) % 4 == 0) then
            return complex.new(base.im ^ exponent.re, 0)
        elseif (math.floor(exponent.re) % 4 == 1) then
            return complex.new(0, base.im ^ exponent.re)
        elseif (math.floor(exponent.re) % 4 == 2) then
            return complex.new(-(base.im ^ exponent.re), 0)
        elseif (math.floor(exponent.re) % 4 == 3) then
            return complex.new(0, -(base.im ^ exponent.re))
        end
    elseif (base:arg() ~= 0) then
        return complex.polar(
            base:abs() ^ exponent.re,
            base:arg() * exponent.re
        )
    else
        return complex.new(base.re ^ exponent.re, 0)
    end
end

function sqrt (x)
    local xx = complex.tocomplex(x)
    return pow(xx, 0.5)
end

-- Trigonometric

function sin (x)
    local xx = complex.tocomplex(x)
    return complex.new(
        math.sin(xx.re) * math.cosh(xx.im),
        math.cos(xx.re) * math.sinh(xx.im)
    )
end

function cos (x)
    local xx = complex.tocomplex(x)
    return complex.new(
        math.cos(xx.re) * math.cosh(xx.im),
        -(math.sin(xx.re)) * math.sinh(xx.im)
    )
end

function tan (x)
    local xx = complex.tocomplex(x)
    return (sin(xx) / cos(xx))
end

function asin (x)
    local xx = complex.tocomplex(x)
    return (-(complex.i) * log(complex.i * xx + sqrt(1 - xx ^ 2)))
end

function acos (x)
    local xx = complex.tocomplex(x)
    return (math.pi / 2 - asin(xx))
end

function atan (x)
    local xx = complex.tocomplex(x)
    return (0.5 * complex.i * log((1 - complex.i * xx) / (1 + complex.i * xx)))
end

-- Hyperbolic

function sinh (x)
    local xx = complex.tocomplex(x)
    return ((exp(x) - exp(-x)) / 2)
end

function cosh (x)
    local xx = complex.tocomplex(x)
    return ((exp(x) + exp(-x)) / 2)
end

function tanh (x)
    local xx = complex.tocomplex(x)
    return (sinh(xx) / cosh(xx))
end

function asinh (x)
    local xx = complex.tocomplex(x)
    return log(xx + sqrt(xx ^ 2 + 1))
end

function acosh (x)
    local xx = complex.tocomplex(x)
    return log(xx + sqrt(xx + 1) * sqrt(xx - 1))
end

function atanh (x)
    local xx = complex.tocomplex(x)
    return (0.5 * log((1 + xx) / (1 - xx)))
end

-- Complex number specific functions ()

function conj (x)
    local xx = complex.tocomplex(x)
    return (xx:conj())
end
function abs (x)
    local xx = complex.tocomplex(x)
    return (xx:abs())
end
function arg (x)
    local xx = complex.tocomplex(x)
    return (xx:arg())
end



-- Module "complex" ... prototype for the complex number objects

module("complex", package.seeall)

-- Assumes number as a complex number
function tocomplex (x)
    if (type(x) == "number") then return new(x, 0) else return x end
end

-- x:conj() ... Complex conjugate
function conj (x)
    return new(x.re, -(x.im))
end

-- x:abs() ... Norm
function abs (x)
    return math.sqrt(x.re ^ 2 + x.im ^ 2)
end

-- x:arg() ... Argument
function arg (x)
    return math.atan2(x.im, x.re)
end

-- Something like operator overloading
complex_meta = {
    -- Addition .. (a+bi)+(c+di) == (a+c)+(b+d)i
    __add = function (x, y)
        local xx = tocomplex(x); local yy = tocomplex(y)
        return new(xx.re + yy.re, xx.im + yy.im)
    end,

    -- Subtraction .. (a+bi)-(c+di) == (a+c)-(b+d)i
    __sub = function (x, y)
        local xx = tocomplex(x); local yy = tocomplex(y)
        return new(xx.re - yy.re, xx.im - yy.im)
    end,

    -- Unary minus .. -(a+bi) == -a-bi
    __unm = function (x)
        local xx = tocomplex(x)
        return new(-xx.re, -xx.im)
    end,

    -- Multiplication .. (a+bi)*(c+di) == (ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i
    __mul = function (x, y)
        local xx = tocomplex(x); local yy = tocomplex(y)
        return new(
            xx.re * yy.re - xx.im * yy.im,
            xx.re * yy.im + xx.im * yy.re
        )
    end,

    -- Division .. (a+bi)/(c+di) == ((ac+bd)+(bc-ad)i)/(c^2+d^2)
    __div = function (x, y)
        local xx = tocomplex(x); local yy = tocomplex(y)
        return new(
            (xx.re * yy.re + xx.im * yy.im) / (yy.re * yy.re + yy.im * yy.im),
            (xx.im * yy.re - xx.re * yy.im) / (yy.re * yy.re + yy.im * yy.im)
        )
    end,

    -- yth power of x
    __pow = function (x, y)
        local xx = tocomplex(x); local yy = tocomplex(y)
        return cmath.pow(xx, yy)
    end,

    -- mod and concat are unsupported
    __mod = function (x, y) error ("unsupported operator") end,
    __concat = function (x, y) error ("unsupported operator") end,

    -- Equality
    __eq = function (x, y)
        if ((x.re == y.re) and (x.im == y.im)) then
            return true
        else
            return false
        end
    end,

    -- Sorry, complex numbers are not comparable...
    __lt = function (x, y) error ("complex numbers are not comparable") end,
    __le = function (x, y) error ("complex numbers are not comparable") end,

    -- tostring()
    __tostring = function (x)
        if (x.re == 0) then
            if (x.im == 0) then
                return "0"
            else
                return "" .. x.im .. "i"
            end
        else
            if (x.im > 0) then
                return "" .. x.re .. "+" .. x.im .. "i"
            elseif (x.im < 0) then
                return "" .. x.re .. x.im .. "i"
            else
                return "" .. x.re
            end
        end
    end,

    -- tonumber() ... works only if it is actually a real number
    __tonumber = function(x)
        if (x.im == 0) then
            return x.re
        else
            return nil
        end

    end,
}

-- Constructor
function new (r, i)
    local cn = {re = r, im = i}
    setmetatable(cn, complex_meta)
    cn.conj = complex.conj
    cn.abs = complex.abs
    cn.arg = complex.arg
    return cn
end

-- Another constructor ... by polar form
function polar (r, theta)
    return new(r * math.cos(theta), r * math.sin(theta))
end

-- complex.i ... imaginary unit
i = complex.new(0, 1)
```

Comment: Could You please clarify Lua version You're using? (I guess, `package.seeall` is only compatible with 5.0 and 5.1)

Comment: I use 5.2.3 on ubuntu 14.04. If it a compatibility issue, how to use complex numbers?

Comment: This is not your code. [Original source](https://gist.github.com/MihailJP/3500284). We only review code that people own; asking for help understanding code that you did not write is off-topic.

Comment: I never asked about any explanation of the code in the module, did I ? I asked for the use of the table. I put here the module because I used a table of complex number. My comment follows the compatibility remark. The module is compatible, the remark was useless ;-) Thanks to the answer I could continue my work, I thanks TickTock very much for is time and knowledge (and kindness).

Comment: Your code wasn't working which makes it off topic anyway. Either you were asking for help with a 3rd party lib (off topic) or your code was broken (off topic). Take your pick.

Comment: was is a pick and where can I find it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to print the numbers, your syntax is wrong.

```
require "complex"
a = complex.new (0,1)
b =    complex.new (7,1)
c = complex.new (1,6.4)
t = {a="a", b="b", c="c"}
print (t["a"])
```

This will only print "a"

```
require "complex"
a = complex.new(0, 1)
b = complex.new(7, 1)
c = complex.new(1, 6.4)
t = {
  a = a,
  b = b,
  c = c
}
print(t.a)
```

Try that

To iterate through the table, you might do this

```
require "complex"
a,b,c = ...
t = ...
for K,V in next,t do
  print(K,V)
end
```

Comment: Ok but how to iterate all the table to print a yields 1i ...

Comment: Edited. Please tell me if that doesn't help

Comment: Just fantastic !